# Send post data from Ajax generated input fields(with same name) to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to post data from input fields to PHP. I have a jQuery script, that adds new input fields (by user clicking the button). All input fields have the same name `input[]`. When i submit the form, and I do `var_dump($_POST)`, all i get is the array with only 1 item in it ( the first input that was there when the page loaded). Does anybody know the way to get data from other input fields, that are dynamically added? Do I need to use JSON for this?

here is the code:

```
<body>
<div id="inp">
 <form action="asd.php" method="POST">
        <p><input type="text" name="input[]"></p>
</div>
<div id="adddiv">
    <input id="add" type="submit" value="+">
    <input id="ok" type="submit" value="ok">
 </form>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#add').click(function(e){  //adds input fields
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#inp').append('<p><input type="text" name="input[]">&nbsp;<input id="del" type="submit" value="-"></p>');
});

$('#inp').on('click', '#del', function(e){  // removes input fields
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('p').remove();
});

});
</script>
```

and now the php file:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);  // shows only 1 item in the array

if(!empty($_POST)){
  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_POST);$i++){
    $data = $_POST['input'][$i];
    echo '<br>' . $data;
  }
}
?>
```

I found a fix to this:

```
<div>
    <form action="process.php" method="POST">
        <div id="inp">
            <p><input type="text" name="input[]"></p>
        </div>
    <div id="adddiv">
        <input id="add" type="submit" value="+">
        <input id="ok" type="submit" value="ok">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: your html part is wrong you have closed div tag after form open tag `<div id="inp">
 <form action="asd.php" method="POST">
        <p><input type="text" name="input[]"></p>
</div>` its wrong

Comment: fixed it, but the problem is still here... still only 1 item in array

Comment: change the code here too

Comment: oh i found the problem. I changed div order a bit.... now, it works. check out the edit

Comment: Yes that's whit i am talking about

Comment: @JosephPP add your solution as an answer instead of editing your question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your HTML is broken, you are closing the "#inp" div in mid form thereby effectively closing the form that is why it only posts the first input
try this

```
<div id="inp">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <p><input type="text" name="input[]"></p>
        <div id="adddiv">
            <input id="add" type="submit" value="+">
            <input id="ok" type="submit" value="ok">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#add').click(function(e){  //adds input fields
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#adddiv').before('<p><input type="text" name="input[]">&nbsp;<input id="del" type="submit" value="-"></p>');
        });

        $('#inp').on('click', '#del', function(e){  // removes input fields
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('p').remove();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: fixed it, but the problem is still here... still only 1 item in array

Comment: please use the code I provided and test again, (i did and it works)